# OkHttp returns 403 as response

Tags: java, api, rest, okhttp

I'm trying to make a request to the Third-party API, but I'm running into some issues using OkHTTP.
I'm using AWS4Signer to sign the request. I'm able to generate the credentials for the same.

```
Request<Void> requestAws = new DefaultRequest<Void>("sts");
        requestAws.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.POST);
        requestAws.setEndpoint(URI.create("third pary api call which uses https"));
        requestAws.addHeader("x-amz-security-token", sessionCredentials.getSessionToken());
        requestAws.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
       
        //sign the request
        AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
        signer.setServiceName(Constant.SERVICE_NAME);
        signer.setRegionName(Constant.AWS_REGION);
        signer.sign(requestAws, new AWSCredentials() {
            
            @Override
            public String getAWSSecretKey() {
                return sessionCredentials.getAccessKeyId();
            }
            
            @Override
            public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
                return sessionCredentials.getSecretAccessKey();
            }
        });
       
        Map<String, String> headers = requestAws.getHeaders();
        String x_date = null;
        String x_token = null;
        String authorization = null;
        String x_content = null;
        //get and assign values
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().equals("x-amz-security-token")) {
                x_token = entry.getValue();
            }
            if (entry.getKey().equals("X-Amz-Date")) {
                x_date = entry.getValue();
            }
            if (entry.getKey().equals("Authorization")) {
                authorization = entry.getValue();
            }
        }
      
       logger.info("Headers body response: " + JsonUtils.jsonize(headers));
       String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(emailRequestBody);
      
       postHandler.post(x_date, x_token, authorization, json);
```

Below is the request code of okHTTP

```
 String post(String x_date, String x_token, String authorization, String json) throws IOException {
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(json, JSON);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https url is here")
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("X-Amz-Date", x_date)
                .addHeader("x-amz-security-token", x_token)
                .addHeader("Authorization", authorization)
                .post(body)
                .build();
        
        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
          return response.body().string();
        }
      }
```

Below is how the request looks like with headers:

```
Request{method=POST, url=https://cbc.com/api/send/email, headers=[Content-Type:application/json, X-Amz-Date:20220125T111056Z, x-amz-security-token:FwoGZXIvYXdzEHUaDF6/kQ0g7Mog7W1f7CK0ATG5xhFIXP34wRjziAkJKhw9vE5cbADBOpji7uqtLp5GLGLay+e9O2deFRB4eSpUMOOThDCEQg1tum43iX4a+8Kikuc3fv5gDjbMrdLJYAK3piYVbOAET8BAXdDdkPZVG+nNu31cEWZe9HC60svIj0m95YZ9Xx5rBIDm0AVWtj4JRCmonNm1ymCNRB4GTjhEzgnxlkqEYfdUivFdlORq/IlIssUzzV04fkr0kiqDiE9GrmU51ijAtb+PBjIt9MWbM8+x4z+y+IV4JFjuK4zrVW3Iaw4xUG/C+mpcCrZrunh+8fWgVTR6In1r, Authorization:AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=medS2y7xvISbOf7ke3IWthyCMV5koeTDD5r3gkxJ/20220125/us-west-2/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token, Signature=d862c9ed8175770244e17fd3cb216c2a92138183ad427ed67fc5f284a1a75266]}
```

Below is the response:

```
Response{protocol=h2, code=403, message=, url=https://cbc.com/api/send/email}
```

Why the response is returning 403? Can someone help me what I missed?  Thank you for your time.